# Can we use same sql database for multiple cache clusters in windows App Fabric?

Tags: caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

We already have Windows AppFabric setup as a cluster for 15 servers and config store is set a SQl server. Now, I want to create a completely different/independent of existing cache cache host and servers in a new data center. Can I use the same sql database as a config store and create a new cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need another database, though of course you can have it on the same SQL instance.